# pyparsing: ensuring all sections are parsed

Tags: pyparsing

I write a parser for evice configuration files. There are a lot of sections for interfaces, they contain some number of configuration commands. And because of the fact that different devices (firmware versions) may have different defaults and I don't know all possible commands at this point --- how to write a parser in this case?

When I write:

```
# for cisco:
iface = header \
    + iftype + ifname \
    + descr \
    + switchport_options \
    + SkipTo(comment).suppress() \
    + comment.suppress()

ifaces = Group(OneOrMore(iface))
```

--- in this case I miss all interfaces with `ip address` before `descr` token. Ok, I know this, I can use `Optional` for every possible command, but there can be other configuration commands which I am unaware of so far.

And I get a list of interfaces without those which were not parsed with my language definition.

I guess I can do this in two passes. First, get all `ifaces` having defined them as "everything from `interface` up to `comment`" and then trying to parse them one by one. And possible exceptions will help me to fine-tune my definitions.

Is this right way?

How can I do this?